# pgfplots is skipping first ytickslabel from file

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex, csv

Rendering the MWE below pgfplots skips the first 'Adiff' label of the CSV.

I'm sure this is a no-brainer and easy karma points for experienced pgfplots users, but I am stomped.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
    at={(0,0)},
    legend cell align=left,
    anchor=north east}}
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={
    /pgfplots/cycle list={%
  {black,fill=gray!80,mark=none},%
  {black,fill=gray!50,mark=none},%
  {black,fill=gray!20,mark=none},%
}
},
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{MoodMeans.csv}
0,1,octant
1,1,Adiff
2,2,Ediff
3,3,Pdiff
4,4,Cdiff
-1,-1,Qdiff
-2,-2,Bdiff
-3,-3,Udiff
-4,-4,Ddiff
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    table/col sep=comma,
    title={Mood changes (means)},
    xlabel=Change,
    yticklabels from table={MoodMeans.csv}{octant},
    width=0.9\columnwidth,
    height=9cm,
    bar width=1.8mm,
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    legend style={
      draw=none,
      at={(0,0)},
      anchor=north east,
      at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.2)}}
  ]

  \addplot table [y expr=\coordindex, x=0] {MoodMeans.csv};
  \addplot table [y expr=\coordindex, x=1] {MoodMeans.csv};
  \legend{Control,Experiment};

  \draw[ultra thin]
  (axis cs:0, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
  -- (axis cs:0, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Means of ``mood changes'' for the two groups.\label{fig:moodmeans}}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

cheers
and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specification what y value (=value of the `\coordindex`) is assigned to the label Adiff etc. in your MWE. You have to add `ytick={0,...,7}` because the row counter starts with 0.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
    at={(0,0)},
    legend cell align=left,
    anchor=north east}}
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={
    /pgfplots/cycle list={%
  {black,fill=gray!80,mark=none},%
  {black,fill=gray!50,mark=none},%
  {black,fill=gray!20,mark=none},%
}
},
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{MoodMeans.csv}
0,1,octant
1,1,Adiff
2,2,Ediff
3,3,Pdiff
4,4,Cdiff
-1,-1,Qdiff
-2,-2,Bdiff
-3,-3,Udiff
-4,-4,Ddiff
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    table/col sep=comma,
    title={Mood changes (means)},
    xlabel=Change,
    ytick={0,...,7},% <- added code
    yticklabels from table={MoodMeans.csv}{octant},
    width=0.9\columnwidth,
    height=9cm,
    bar width=1.8mm,
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    legend style={
      draw=none,
      at={(0,0)},
      anchor=north east,
      at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.2)}}
  ]

  \addplot table [y expr=\coordindex, x=0] {MoodMeans.csv};
  \addplot table [y expr=\coordindex, x=1] {MoodMeans.csv};
  \legend{Control,Experiment};

  \draw[ultra thin]
  (axis cs:0, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
  -- (axis cs:0, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Means of ``mood changes'' for the two groups.\label{fig:moodmeans}}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks esdd! I'm not sure I've commended you enough or the right way. Let me know what I have missed if you think I have.

Comment: Apparently I'm too much of a newbie to vote up your answer.